# spring boot LazyInitializationException fat client application

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am fairly new to spring boot but try to apply it to my - maybe old fashioned - client server project with a JavaFX front end. The data I am working on is basically a tree, were each node holds several lists with time series information. In order to not load the entire database at start up, eager loading of the time series lists is not an option. The trouble is, that depending on the user selection I need to fetch different time list data in the JavaFX View-Controller, and at this time the session is already closed resulting in the LazyInitializationException.

So I was reading many posts here, but my understanding of the spring framework is too limited. If I get it right the often stated OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter and OpenSessionInViewFilter are not applicable for me, as these Filters relate to web apps and not to fat client applications?! If I am wrong here, could someone please explain to me how to apply them in a JavaFX controller class? If I am right, what would be the best solution to solve this issue? So I guess it all boils down to: What annotations are required and where?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When the user selects something, call a transactional service method. Spring will thus get a freshly opened EntityManager, you'll get the data, return from the method, and Spring will commit the transaction and close the EntityManager. Post your code.

Comment: But that would mean, that I have to have for each List a method in the service, right? That feels a little like the old days when I had to write for each attribute the JDBC calls myself. I thought that spring boot aims to take that away from me. Any way to keep the session open and just close it, once the application exits?